# How to print all the elements of an array in MASM?

Tags: assembly, masm32, irvine32

How do I print all the elements of an array?

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
list DWORD 10,30,50,70,80,65
listSize = ($ - list) / 4

.code
main PROC
mov eax, 0
mov esi, list
mov ecx, listSize

L1:
    mov eax, list[esi * TYPE list]
    call WriteInt
    call CrlF
    inc esi

    loop L1

exit
main ENDP

end main
```

This prints out all 0's. What am I doing wrong, I know its something stupid but please help.

Comment: Since you use `esi` as index, `mov esi, list` should be `mov esi, 0`.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez no, he scales by 4 in the address  as `* TYPE list` so that's actually correct.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez I changed "inc esi" to "add esi, 4" but it still prints out all zeroes.

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks guys.

Comment: The program prints the element with + in front of the elements. Is there any way that I can avoid it?

Comment: Since you use a library (irvine32.inc) see if it has a function that does that. Otherwise you will have to code your own int-to-string conversion.

Comment: @jester Thanks, using WriteDec instead of WriteInt did the trick.